# Firebase query to get the key where 2 entries match

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, querying

Can someone explain so me how I write a query to get back the right key value by querying for the number and the time. 
Numbers in my database are often the same but there is never a number and a time the same.

```
   "key1": {
    "number": "123456789",
    "test": "testing",
    "time": 1499175554444
},
   "key2": {
    "number": "123456789",
    "test": "testing",
    "time": 1499175551923
}
```

number is a String and time is a long.

Here is what I have been trying:

```
Query query = ref.child("test")
.child("test2").child("test3").orderByChild("number")
.equalTo("123456789");
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

    @Override                                  
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {                                      
     for (DataSnapshot appleSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren() ) {                                                
        String key = appleSnapshot.getKey();

        Toast.makeText(getContext(), key, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}           
 return;
 }
```

This will always give me key1.

How do I add the time parameter into the query so I only get the key that matches the time and the number?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try using log.d and check what count does dataSnapshot.getChildren() gives.

Comment: Your `return` statement breaks from the `for` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
Query query = ref.child("test")
.child("test2")
.child("test3")
.orderByChild("number")
.equalTo("123456789");
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

@Override                                  
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {                                      
 for (DataSnapshot appleSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren() ) {                                                
    Key key = appleSnapshot.getValue(Key.class);
    Long time1 = 1499175554444;
    Long time2 = key.getTime();
    if (time2 == time1 ) {
       String key = appleSnapshot.getKey();
       Toast.makeText(getContext(), key, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }   
    }           

}
```

Comment: The only issue with this is the  key.getTime(); can not resolve method. Have you any idea how that could be fixed?

Comment: You have to create a custom object of type Key. Refer to the class Post in this link under updating or deleting data. Make sure to add getters and setters. [https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write)